Blazor Local Accounts: Add to existing database
As a proof of concept, I wrote a prototype Blazor Server application that uses local accounts for authentication.  That all works perfectly.
Now I need to add all the required local account tables into an existing production database.  The database is on a hosted server and I can't install Visual Studio on that server.  How do I create the local account tables?  Can I simply use SQL Management Studio to script the new tables (including data) and run the script on the production database?

Is this really related to the SQL language? (Or would the  tag suit better?)
